# Custom AngularJS directives not registering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I'm attempting to implement a few directives in my AngularJS website to allow it to be SEO cached with custom page titles/descriptions.

I've set up a module (`angular.module('website.directives', [])`), and it is being included in my app (`angular.module('website', [...'website.directives'...])`). I know the file with my directives is being properly downloaded and run. The file looks like this:

```
angular.module('website.directives').directive('viewTitle', function() {
    restrict = 'E';
    link($scope, element) {
        console.log("Linking view title.");
        var text = element.text();
        element.remove();
        $('html head title').text(text);
    }
});

angular.module('website.directives').directive('viewDesc', function() {
    restrict = 'E';
    link($scope, element) {
        console.log("Linking view description.");
        var text = element.text();
        element.remove();
        $('html head meta[name=description]').attr('content', text);
    }
});
```

Meanwhile in my templates, I use them more or less like you'd expect:

```
<view-title>My Website</view-title>
<view-desc>A short description of my website.</view-desc>
```

Not only is the text not being removed and the title/description not being updated, but the `console` statements in my `link` functions aren't being called at all. I'm not sure why my directives aren't being used at all.

If there's any more information you need, I'm happy to provide it. Thank you!

EDIT: Apologies, I tried to translate my directive from TypeScript to Javascript to make it easier for people to read, but on second thought that was a terrible idea. I should have just provided the code. That said, it looks like this:

```
export class ViewTitleDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'E';
    link($scope, element: JQuery) {
        console.log("Linking view title.");
        var text = element.text();
        element.remove();
        $('html head title').text(text);
    }
}

export class ViewDescriptionDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'E';
    link($scope, element: JQuery) {
        console.log("Linking view description.");
        var text = element.text();
        element.remove();
        $('html head meta[name=description]').attr('content', text);
    }
}

angular.module('website.directives').directive('viewTitle', () => ViewTitleDirective);
angular.module('website.directives').directive('viewDesc', () => ViewDescriptionDirective);
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you are bootstrapping your application in the body tag.

```
eg: <body data-ng-app="app">
```

Try moving that to the html tag

```
<html data-ng-app="app">
```

This will include your `<head>` in the application DOM compilation and should allow your directive to fire in the title and content tags.

Comment: The statement 'This will initialize your application before the head' is not correct. It will make head resided in root element but certainly not will initialize the app before DOM is ready.

Comment: @estus You are correct. Thanks for pointing out my poor choice in description. A better choice would have been "This will include your <head> in the application DOM compilation ...". This is what happens when sleep eludes me for days! I am updating my answer to reflect this.